# Type hinting a decorator that wraps a generator in Python

Tags: python, python-decorators, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I'm new to type hinting in Python and would like to know best practices. I'm not sure if I'm running up against a limitation of mypy, or my own lack of knowledge.

#### Setup

Here I have:

- A decorator `coro_starter` whose job is to call `next()` on any arbitrary generator so it's ready
- A generator `echo_round` (really a coroutine here, I believe) that will round any number I send into it
- A few sample calls to the decorated generator

I'm not confident I have type hinted all this correctly. If I've erred, please let me know.

#### Two Questions

1. Is there a way to avoid `cast()`ing `coro_starter`? Currently, If I use `return coro_wrapper` alone I get:

> Incompatible return value type (got "Callable[P, Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]]", expected "Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]")  [return-value]mypy
> (function) coro_wrapper: _Wrapped[P@coro_starter, Generator[YieldType@coro_starter, SendType@coro_starter, ReturnType@coro_starter], P.args, Generator[YieldType@coro_starter, SendType@coro_starter, ReturnType@coro_starter]]

2. Any suggestions to resolve the following error on `g = echo_round`? Mypy complains:

> "Generator[float, float | int | str | None, str]" not callable  [operator]mypy
> (function) echo_round: Generator[float, float | int | str | None, str]

*Important: I'm using Mypy in strict mode, and would prefer to avoid using `Any` and minimize the use of type-unsafe things like `cast()`.*

Thank you in advance to anyone that can help!

### The Code

```py
from functools import wraps
from typing import Callable, Generator, ParamSpec, TypeVar, cast

P = ParamSpec("P")
YieldType = TypeVar("YieldType")
SendType = TypeVar("SendType")
ReturnType = TypeVar("ReturnType")


def coro_starter(
    func: Callable[P, Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]]
) -> Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]:
    @wraps(func)
    def coro_wrapper(
        *args: P.args,
        **kwargs: P.kwargs,
    ) -> Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]:
        f = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(f)
        return f

    return coro_wrapper


@coro_starter
def echo_round() -> Generator[float, float | int | str | None, str]:
    sent: float | int | str | None = 1
    while sent:
        try:
            sent = yield round(float(sent))
            print(f"round sent val {sent}")
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f"Got error '{e}'. This function only accepts numbers.")
            exit(0)
    return "Done"


g = echo_round()
print(f"first call {g.send(2.5)}")
print(f"second call {g.send('8')}")
```

Comment: Change `coro_starter`'s return type to `Callable[P, Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]]` and all your errors should go away. `coro_starter` isn't returning a generator, it's returning a function which makes a generator.